# How to check if FileSystemEntity is a Directory

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-io

**Problem**

I get the `FileSystemEntity` list and want to select only Directories from it. So I create a new list and remove all entity types from it except `Directory`. However, the list just happens to be empty (it is guaranteed that subdirectories exist).

```
final inputDir = Directory(path); // home

final onlyDirs = await inputDir.list().toList(); // get subdirs
onlyDirs.removeWhere((element) => element.runtimeType != Directory); // remove all except Directory
```

**My solution**

I was trying to check `element.runtimeType is! Directory`, but it does not work at all. Debugger says that element.runtimeType is _Directory, but obviously I can't use private class in my comparator.

**Question**

How to remove all entities except directories from the `List<FileSystemEntity>`?

Comment: *"How to check if FileSystemEntity is a Directory"* - `final onlyDirs = await inputDir.list().where((fse) => fse is Directory).toList();`

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. But linter suggested to use `whereType<T>()`
So it goes `final onlyDirs = inputDir.whereType<Directory>().toList();`

Comment: you cannot call `whereType` on `inputDir` - `inputDir` is `Directory` object, not `Iterable` - you would need to create a `List` with files and folders first and then another filtered `List` that contains only folders

Comment: Yes, what I meant was that using `whereType<>` is visually more convenient than checking by a lambda. The problem is solved anyway.